# Redirect URI into subpage.php and read is as parameter by .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, uri, redirect

I would like to redirect URI into subpage.php and read is as parameter (by $_GET method).

**Example 1**:

http://homepage.com/wap/show_counties.php?id_county=51&char_county=&lang=en

into

http://homepage.com/controller.php?url=wap/show_counties.php?id_county=51&char_county=&lang=en (??? - can I pass url parameter like this?)

**Example 2**:

http://homepage.com/accommodation/hostel-star-bratislava

into

http://homepage.com/controller.php?url=accommodation/hostel-star-bratislava

**Example 3**:

http://homepage.com/en/search-in-page-12.html?ordering=newest&searchphrase=any&searchword=do%25252525252525252525252B700%252525252525

into

http://homepage.com/controller.php?url=en/search-in-page-12.html?ordering=newest&searchphrase=any&searchword=do%25252525252525252525252B700%252525252525 (??? - can I pass url parameter like this?)

EDIT: I would like to make url redirection by .htaccess

Could you help me please?
Regards

Jan Zitniak

Comment: Help us help you. What have you tried? What's not working?

Comment: You start with "I would like to redirect" but end with "Main URL shouldn't be redirected". What exactly do you want to achieve? Browser redirection or perhaps call a different script based on the URL?

Comment: Sorry for my explanation. I would like to make url redirection by .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with mod_rewrite. What you want to do can be described like so:

- The request uri should be passed to a specific file in a get variable
- If there is an original query string, it should be retained

You can do this with the `QSA` (query string append) flag in mod_rewrite. In addition to that, in the example below I add a condition that checks if the file that is requested does not exist. This prevents the rule from matching itself (controller.php exists) and prevents the rule from working on files that are typically not handled by a controller (js/css/images). Add the following to the beginning of the `.htaccess` in your www-root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /controller.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

See [the documentation for mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) in general and the [document about flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html) specific for more information.